# DotNetOpenAuth Failing to work on Live Server

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I worked on a sample application integrating OpenID into ASP.NET Web Forms. It works fine when hosted locally on my machine. However, when I uploaded the application to a live server, it started giving "Login Failed".

You can try a sample here: http://samples.bhaidar.net/openidsso

Any ideas?

Here is the source code that fails to process the OpenID response:

```
   private void HandleOpenIdProviderResponse()
    {
        // Define a new instance of OpenIdRelyingParty class
        using (var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
        {
            // Get authentication response from OpenId Provider Create IAuthenticationResponse instance to be used
            // to retreive the response from OP
            var response = openid.GetResponse();

            // No authentication request was sent
            if (response == null) return;

            switch (response.Status)
            {
                // If user was authenticated
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                    // This is where you would look for any OpenID extension responses included
                    // in the authentication assertion.
                    var fetchResponse = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();

                    // Store the "Queried Fields"
                    Session["FetchResponse"] = fetchResponse;

                    // Use FormsAuthentication to tell ASP.NET that the user is now logged in,
                    // with the OpenID Claimed Identifier as their username.
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
                    break;
                // User has cancelled the OpenID Dance
                case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                    this.loginCanceledLabel.Visible = true;
                    break;
                // Authentication failed
                case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                    this.loginFailedLabel.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hello Bill. I have the same problem. I am trying to authenticate with google. It works fine in testing, but return 'Failed' status on my live link. On the URL that you have shared above, I have noticed that it is working fine. Can you share the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turn on logging](http://tinyurl.com/dnoalogs) on your live server and inspect them for additional diagnostics.  It's most likely a firewall or permissions problem on your server that prevents outbound HTTP requests.

You may also find it useful to look at the `IAuthenticationResponse.Exception` property when an authentication fails for clues.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the reply. Logging already enabled. Where can I find the "RelyingParty.log" ? I didn't change anything in the log4net web.config section. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew suggested, check the exception.  In my case, my production server's time & date were off and it wouldn't authenticate because the ticket expired.

Comment: How to solve this issue? i can see my production server's time is in some other timezone. And this seems to be the only problem which might be occuring